# indexError: list index out of range when attempting to encrypt a text

Tags: python, list, indexing, error-handling

For some reason my code results in "IndexError: list index out of range" when inputing a plain text of the book hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy and a key of "HEY". I have no idea what could cause this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
def vigenere_enc( plain, key ):

    upper_plain = simplify_string( plain )
    plain_ls = list( upper_plain )
    key_ls = list( key )
    alpha = [ "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" , "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" , "U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z" ]
    ls = []

    for let, key in zip(plain, cycle(key)):
        shift_location =  (alpha.index( key )) + (alpha.index( let ))

        if shift_location > 26:

            shift_from_beg = ( shift_location - 26)
            add_let = alpha[ shift_from_beg ]
            ls.append( add_let )

        else:

            else_add_let = alpha[ shift_location ]
            ls.append( else_add_let )

    string = ''.join( ls )
    return string
```

Comment: One thing for sure, the book hitchhiker's guide to the galaxy has nothing to do with this. Can you elaborate more on the cycle function, is it the one off `itertools` ? `plain` and `cycle(key)` should have the same number of elements and the number must be lower than `alpha`.

Comment: @Lambasoft it is the one off itertools! plain and key do not have the same number of elements, which is why i thought cycle would continue looping "HEY" to encrypt all the letters.. is that a problem?

Comment: You're checking if shift_location > 26, so if shift_location was equal to 26, it would do `else_add_let = alpha[ shift_location ]` but `alpha[26]` doesn't exist, because the indexing count starts from 0 so the maximum value you must check is `alpha[25]` 
To fix that, change the if statement to `if shift_location >= 26:`